# Fragment global variable not being remove when destroy fragment-activity

Tags: android, activity-lifecycle, fragment-lifecycle

I used to think that all of global variable is destroy it self when fragment is destroy (in onDestroy) or maybe sometime it will removed by Garbage Collector.But when trying to check the variable instance in onDestroy,it not be clean up by fragment.As i remember onDestroy is 
 **called to do final cleanup of the fragment's state** (follow to this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onDestroy()) so why the variable is still not been removed? ( i also checked inside onDetach but the result is still the same)

Comment: `onDestroy` simply means the fragment is about to be destroyed... not already destroyed.

Comment: thanks for reply @GiddyNaya ,but reference to that link,the state will be destroy it state.so if not,when will all the variable be destroy

Comment: `onDetach()` is the method you're looking for. Read more https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onDetach()

Comment: @RahulKhurana oh,sorry i will add more in my question.i was try to check the variable after super.onDetach().it still not be clean ( i try to delay the check for 2-3 second).

Comment: @Nghiem Ba Cuong Yes the app state will be destroyed `but only after it has been executed.` Any block you specify under `onDestroy` will be executed just before the fragment is destroyed that is what it implies until then your variables still exist.

Comment: @GiddyNaya great answer.so is there anyway can i check that all of the variable is remove or any callback??

Comment: @NghiemBaCuong What do you want to do with those variables?

Comment: @NghiemBaCuong Have you define your variable as a static variable?

Comment: Nice reply @Rahul Khurana. it would be helpful to share your reason for tracking the existence of the variables to determine the right answer to give you.

Comment: @GiddyNaya oh, i'm new Android Developer and i just really want control,handle the lifecycle and all about it for after development.^^.so any knowledge of this u guys can help me to know it.many thanks to u all supported

Comment: @AshishKakadiya no,it just a normal variable

Comment: @RahulKhurana i answer your question above 2 comment but SOF not allow tag 2 people.sr bout that

Comment: @NghiemBaCuong You can also destroy your variable  onDestroy() method

Comment: @NghiemBaCuong don't worry about these types of customization in the begining phase just learn about the lifecycle steps, passing arguments, both Implicit and Explicit Intent